# custom chessboard with animation

Tags: animations, chess, xskak, chessboard

I'm new to latex! I've created the chessboard on the picture below and I want to make an animation with specific movement for the knight and loop it! How can I do that? Also I'd like to know how to iclude the controls below. I've read the documentation of xskak but I am missing something...Can you help me?
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{3x5}{maxfield=e3}

\begin{document}

\chessboard[style=3x5,setblack={Na1},showmover=false]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the animate package for the animation (and a pdf viewer that supports this). E.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{3x5}{maxfield=e3,showmover=false}
\setchessboard{style=3x5}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{1}
\chessboard[setblack={Na1}]
\newframe
\chessboard[setblack={Nb3}]
\newframe
\chessboard[setblack={Nc1}]
\newframe
\chessboard[setblack={Nd3}]
\newframe
\chessboard[setblack={Ne1}]
\newframe
\chessboard[setblack={Nc2}]
\end{animateinline}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the animation doesnt seem to work in my pdf viewer :(

Comment: My pdf reader is Document Viewer which comes deafult with Ubuntu

Comment: It works in Adobe! BTW a small question, see i want to write a knights tour animation on a 8x8 board. Suppose if  i would like to put a "X" inside the square if the knight has visited then what command should i use?? Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: @crskhr Don't ask new questions in comments. Create a new question with a suitable minimal example -- and check the documentation of chessboard first.